# Register Script Troubles, PHP, Query is not being executed

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to create a simple register script for my website, however there is something wrong with the query or something with my code.

The query in question is this (yet again Updated) :

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $mysqlusr  = "website";
    $mysqlpass = "OOPS!";
    $mysqlhost = "localhost";
    $mysqldb   = "website";
    $username  = $_REQUEST['username'];
    $password  = $_REQUEST['password'];
    $email     = $_REQUEST['email'];
    $day       = $_REQUEST['day'];
    $month = $_REQUEST['month'];
    $year  = $_REQUEST['year'];
    $emailcheck;
    $daycheck;
    $monthcheck;
    $yearcheck;
    $usernameinuse;
    $attempt  = $_REQUEST['attempt'];
    $dbhandle = mysql_connect($mysqlhost, $mysqlusr, $mysqlpass);
    $selected = mysql_select_db("website") or die("Could not select database");
    if ($attempt == true && $usernameinuse == false) {
        $query2 = msql_query("INSERT INTO users (username, password, email, day, month, year) VALUES ('$username', '$password', '$email', '$day', '$month', '$year')");
    } else {
        if ($attempt == true && $usernameinuse == true) {
            echo '<div class="alert alert-error"><b>Oh Snap!</b> Username Or Email is in use!</div>';
        }
    }
    if ($_SESSION['state'] == 'logged-in') {
        echo '<div class="alert alert-error"><b>Oh Snap!</b> You are already logged in!</div>';
    } elseif ($_SESSION['state'] == 'no-user') {
        echo '
    <form action="register.php" metod="post">
    Username: <input type="text" name="username" value="" MAXLENGTH="16" /><br>
    Password: <input type="password" name="password" value="" MAXLENGTH="25"/><br>
    Email<br><small>(Make sure this is your correct email as you will need to confirm your user!)</small>:<br> <input type="text" name="email" value=""MAXLENGTH="50"/><br>
    Day of Birth: <select name="day">';
        for ($i = 1; $i <= 31; $i++) {
            echo '<option value=' . $i . '>' . $i . '</option>';
        }
        echo '
    </select><br>
    Month of Birth: <select name="month">
    <option value="1">January</option>
    <option value="2">February</option>
    <option value="3">March</option>
    <option value="4">April</option>
    <option value="5">May</option>
    <option value="6">June</option>
    <option value="7">July</option>
    <option value="8">August</option>
    <option value="9">September</option>
    <option value="10">October</option>
    <option value="11">November</option>
    <option value="12">December</option>
    </select><br>

    Year of Birth: <select name="year">';
        for ($i = 2014; $i > 1900; $i--) {
            echo '<option value=' . $i . '>' . $i . '</option>';
        }
        echo '</select>
    <br>
    <button type="submit" name="attempt" value="true" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="icon-file"></i> Register</button>

    </form>
    ';
    }
    if ($attempt == true) {
        $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '" . $username . "' OR email = '" . $email . "'");
        if (mysql_num_rows($query) > 0) {
            $usernameinuse = true;
        } else {
            $usernameinuse = false;
        }
    }
?>
```

I have to add some more text apparently, well.... HERE IT IS!

Comment: `if($attempt == true and $usernameinuse = false) {` - the false part should be double ==

Comment: What about the `and`? Shouldn't it be `&&`?

Comment: Remember that `mysql_*` are **deprecated** in the last version of PHP, and will be removed in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax of [`mysql_connect()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php) is wrong:

```
$dbhandle = mysql_connect($mysqlhost, $mysqlusr, $mysqlpass, $mysqlusr)
                                                          // ^ This is wrong!
            or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");
```

FYI, the syntax is:

```
resource mysql_connect (
  [ string $server = ini_get("mysql.default_host")
  [, string $username = ini_get("mysql.default_user")
  [, string $password = ini_get("mysql.default_password")
  [, bool $new_link = false [, int $client_flags = 0 ]]]]]
)
```

Also, you have a equal here, not equivalent:

```
if($attempt == true and $usernameinuse = false) {
                                    // ^ Replace with ==
```

Comment: Do you know the syntax? New connection should be either `true` or `false`. It is not database selection here.

Comment: I fixed that and now my register form disapears and the data is not inserted into the table

Comment: Did you try to fix the double `==` thing?

Comment: wait, would the $server be the host?

Comment: `resource mysql_connect (
  [ string $mysqlhost = ini_get("mysql.default_host")
  [, string $mysqlusr = ini_get("mysql.default_user")
  [, string $mysqlpass = ini_get("mysql.default_password")
  [, bool $new_link = false [, int $client_flags = 0 ]]]]]
)` So the new connection would be this?

Comment: perhaps could you edit that syntax to fit my usr, host and pass? because I don't understand....

Comment: Yes. And remove the `$mysqlusr` at the last.

Comment: so what would it be instead?

Comment: because that leaves me with `resource mysql_connect ( [ string $mysqlhost = ini_get("mysql.default_host") [, string  = ini_get("mysql.default_user") [, string $mysqlpass = ini_get("mysql.default_password") [, bool $new_link = false [, int $client_flags = 0 ]]]]] )`

Comment: And most important - `mysql_*` functions are `DEPRECATED`! Start using `PDO` instead.

Comment: Dude, the syntax is wrong! You are mixing up `mysqli_connect` and `mysql_connect`.

Comment: Praveen, so without the user it would be : `resource mysql_connect (
  [ string $server = ini_get("mysql.default_host")
  [, string $password = ini_get("mysql.default_password")
  [, bool $new_link = false [, int $client_flags = 0 ]]]]
)`

Comment: Dude, change it to: `$dbhandle = mysql_connect($mysqlhost, $mysqlusr, $mysqlpass)`

Comment: I did that, and still the data isnt in the table

Comment: Yup. Saw that. I am checking it. :)

Comment: Dude, many places you have just `$_REQUEST`??? What's that??? You need something like `$_REQUEST["username"]` or something that way!!!

Comment: Or even switch to MYSQLI_*

Comment: doesnt putting it like this : $variable = $_REQUEST does this automatically?

Comment: @HubertKaluzny Also dude, change `if ($attempt == true and $usernameinuse == false) {` to `&&` and not `and`.

Comment: Nopes. It doesn't. You need to put individual indices.

Comment: Is there anything else? Because the data is still not being inserted >_>

Comment: Dude, you are bad. I will format the code in the question, you follow it. :)

Comment: So, is it working now. What's the problem are you facing. I don't see any potential issues. :)

Comment: try it yourself www.alerios.co.uk/register.php cuz im not seeing any data in the tables still ;(

Comment: what about the random ; inbetween variables?

Comment: well I updated the code on my website and still i dont get the table info >_>

Comment: You had `;;` and that got converted to this. :)

Comment: Okay. Now what's the issue? Still the same?

Comment: is there anything server side that i need to know in order for this to work apart from mysql itself

Comment: Nopes. Nothing wrong with the code. Lets wait for other answers. :)

Comment: im going to try this but with root user instead

Comment: wait is this line correct?   `$query2 = msql_query("INSERT INTO users (username, password, email, day, month, year) VALUES ('$username', '$password', '$email', '$day', '$month', '$year')"); `

Comment: The reason why it doesnt get inserted is because it doesnt get that far. i have added an echo into the if statement that inserts the data but  it didnt echo

Comment: if your so good to tell that to people why dont you sort out the mistake -.-

Comment: also its the second query thats causing the problem

Comment: Awesome! I am like in half sleep, it is 2 AM midnight here. :) :D